# ASHX handler wont fire when path is entered

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, ashx, virtual-directory

I have a file directory that can be access directly from the URL

e.g.

http://website.com/DirectoryName/folder/downloadpdf.pdf

I need to control whom can access the files so I have created a ASHX handler so I check permissions of the user.

however, when I access http://website.com/DirectoryName/ the handler doesnt get called.

I believe its something to do with my config, I have

```
  <location path="DirectoryName">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="PSHandler" path="DirectoryName/*" verb="*" type="ProjectName.PSHandler"/>
      </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Different way - IIS 6?

```
  <location path="DirectoryName">
    <system.web>
      <httpHandlers>
        <add path="DirectoryName/*" verb="*" type="ProjectName.PSHandler, PSHandler"/>
      </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Is there something wrong with the above?

the ashx file

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="PSHandler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web

Public Class PSHandler : Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
        context.Response.Write("Hello World")
    End Sub


    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

FYI this is by running locally using IIS Express

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an `ashx` handler in your solution? Or do you have a generic class tha implements an `ihttphandler`? The ashx generic handler need to be requested on its own actual url... Or that is at least the normal use case for an ashx handler. Anyway could it be that you have one extra level of `DirectoryName` in your config?

Comment: Yes I have `PSHandler.ashx`file in the root of my application. and yes it does implement `ihttphandler` DirectoryName is also in the root so its after the .com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are very close. One thing is you will need to write file to response.

```
public class PSHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Path);
        string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/DirectoryName/" + fileName);

        // Check permission of user

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="PS" path="DirectoryName/*" verb="*" 
       type="ProjectName.PSHandler, ProjectName" 
       preCondition="integratedMode"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

### Update

First of all, replace ***httpHandlers*** with ***authorization*** tag.

```
<location path="DirectoryName">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Then add ***handler*** inside application's **web.config**.

```
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <add name="PS" path="DirectoryName/*" verb="*" 
           type="ProjectName.PSHandler, ProjectName" 
           preCondition="integratedMode"/>
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Then copy and paste the following PSHandler code.

```
Public Class PSHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)
        Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Path)
        Dim filePath As String = context.Server.MapPath(Convert.ToString("~/DirectoryName/") & fileName)

        ' Check permission of user. If permission denied, display 404 -
        ' context.Server.Transfer("~/404.aspx")

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        context.Response.WriteFile(filePath)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Reqeust URL should be like this -

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/DirectoryName/downloadpdf.pdf
```

OR

```
http://localhost:xxxx/DirectoryName/downloadpdf.pdf
```

Please make sure *downloadpdf.pdf* file exists in *DirectoryName* folder.

*If it is still doesn't work, please create a new Web Application, and test the above code. I have tested and it works fine.*

Comment: Thanks, are you saying I don't need the `<Location>` element anymore?

Comment: You are correct you do not need it, but you still need to restrict access that folder for everyone. *For example, `<location path="DirectoryName"><system.web><authorization><deny users="*"/>`*

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still wont fire the `ProcessRequest` function (Wont hit my breakpoint) not sure what else I can tell you that you wouldn't know. (Actually I have posted the ashx file) I will upvote it though

Comment: *PSHandler* you posted won't work. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I am going to do what you said and create a new website app as it wont work. You said you tested the above however, I noticed in your handler code that the two methods do not implement IHttpRequest e.g. Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest. How did you get it to build?